# Random accessing of entires in a zip in the asset

Tags: android, zip

I need to find an entry with a name, and then read its content to find another entry it refers to, and then read that entry in a ZIP file asset. How can I achieve this in memory without copying the ZIP asset to a file or extract everything of the ZIP file into a temporary location?

`ZipInputStream` seems to support only forward reading because it uses `InputStream`. I guess I could keep forward-reading to the end of the ZIP file, and if the entry is not found, I could wrap to the beginning by creating a new ZipInputStream of the same ZIP file and search from there again, but this sounds very awkward.

`ZipFile` seems to require a `File`, and it seems there is no way to get `File` for an asset.